# Apexchart react js xaxis lable custom css not working

Tags: html, css, reactjs, apexcharts

[image]

Facing issue in React Apexchart, not apply CSS on text like textoverflow etc.
Please refer below link

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-wu-8wp0ib?file=/src/App.js

solution with example

Comment: The attached image link not working! Could you please provide more information in other way e.g. code-sandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-wu-8wp0ib?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You can access it's element (`tspan`) via css add your styles

like this :

```
.apexcharts-text tspan {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response but not affected by this CSS.

Comment: your welcome, could you please provide more information or make codesandbox for it ?

Comment: Please refer this link:https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-wu-8wp0ib?file=/src/App.js